# divisibility of class numbers of composite two abelian number fields

Tags: number-theory, algebraic-number-theory, ideal-class-group

Let $p$ be a regular prime i.e. $p\nmid h_p$, ($h_p$ denotes the class number of $\mathbb{Q}(\mu_p)$).
Let $F$ be an abelian number field such that $p\nmid h_F$  and  $p\nmid [F:\mathbb{Q}]$.

Do we have $p\nmid h_{F(\mu_p)}$?

I hope it holds, but  in general the following  is wrong:

Let $K,L$  be two number fields such that $p\nmid h_K h_L$, and $p\nmid [KL:K][KL:L]$, then $p\nmid h_{KL}$.

It's easy to find lots of examples from quadratic fields, for instance, take $p=3, K=\mathbb{Q}(i),L=\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{23})$.  $h_{KL}=3$

Comment: Download pari, familiarize yourself with the program, and find as many counter-examples as you like.

Comment: @franzlemmermeyer Thank you a lot!  I'll delete this question.